# Deploy Azure function from GitHub actions to Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am new to Azure and i would like to deploy a folder with my function azure (python file) and create a function in my function app. Do i need a function.json file and what is it for? I am using GitHub actions as CI / CD. Which method can I use? ZIP deploy, Storage Azure deploy, serverless, other? I tested a lot of things with no results.

Comment: [RTM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies). Your question is asking for a training on Azure Function Deployment. You need to be more specific.

Comment: @Kashyap thank you for your answer, I would like to deploy a folder with my python file to an app function. Basically as soon as I make a modification on my code in my github repo, it uploads the modifications to my azure portal

Answer (score 0):

[The manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies):

- Which has a section: [Source Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies#source-control).
- Which points to: [Continuous deployment for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment)

Comment: i use a consumption plan (linux) and python for runtime, it's compatible with Kudu system? it's working with container system ?